# Call .net methods into java without using C/C

Tags: native-methods

Can anybody explain how can i call .net methods(from .dll) in my java code but i dont want to write/use C/C++ Code please expalin it Step by Step

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us any information to work off (How large are the two projects? Are you forced to use a specific CLR/JRE? Can they be two separate processes or do you just need to access a bunch of methods? Stuff like that), but I can point you in a general direction...

[IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) is an implementation of Java that runs on the CLR. If you run your Java program in there, you can interop with any other .NET language easily.

If you can't use this for some reason, then you're probably going to have to embed Mono in your application and write some JNI bindings to start an instance of the CLR, then load and invoke your code.

If you've got a small amount of methods, consider just porting the code to Java instead of creating this huge system in order to get a small amount of functionality.

I can't explain it step by step because you haven't provided very much information as to what restrictions you have or how it needs to be done. Also, this isn't something trivial. You're trying to get two language runtimes to interact with each other without using native code, when native code is the only thing either runtime can interoperate with.

Comment: i simply follwing these steps but i am stuck in further :            1.Simple load the .dll file in static block.  2.Create the native methods 3.Create the .h file by javah command . and finally didnt get any idea how shuld i further continue???

Comment: Disregard most of that, this library looks like exactly what you're looking for: http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/